# Where, in the Developer Console, to download gitkit-signin-buttom.html file?

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I've been working through the Google Identity Toolkit tutorial, step by step, and finally after getting things configured in the Developer Console, I started to work on the front end code, when I came across the following line ([on this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend)):

> The code to put in the `<head>` can be downloaded from Developer Console
>   as `gitkit-signin-button.html`

For the life of me, I can't seem to find where, in the Developer Console, to download the `gitkit-signin-button.html` file. Does anyone know where to find this file?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the outdated documentation. The Identity Toolkit page in Google Developer Console no longer displays the download link of the `gitkit-signin-button.html`, since the html content is directly listed just below the line you referred to.

If you have not tried, I would suggest to start from one of the [quick start web applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/) (Python, Java, NodeJs, Ruby, PHP etc.) which contains code for a barebone web site using Google Identity Toolkit.

Comment: I assume from your answer that this is irrelevant now, but in the example code on that page, it says: `<!-- ...The html you download from Developer Console will be tailored for your site -->`. So, is that tailoring unimportant now? Also, thanks for your help!

Comment: The tailoring is still needed. For the Sign In *button*, the change is pretty straightforward - just set the widgetUrl to be your page where Google Identity Toolkit javascript widget is rendered.

For the Sign In *widget* page, you can copy the auto-generated json format config string at the bottom of Google Identity Toolkit API setting page in Google Developer Console, and paste the string as the `var config = {...}` in your html file for the Sign In widget.